# So much is at stake

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary

In this sentence:

> *So much is at stake* that courses in foreign languages are often inadequate training grounds, in and of themselves, for the successful learning of a second language.

I have parsed the first clause 'So much is at stake' as

(b) So  (=adjective modifying ‘much’)
(c) Much (=noun indicating a large quantity or degree of life possibilities)
(d)  is (=verb)
(e) at stake  (=idiomatic complement, meaning ‘at risk’ ‘being risked.’)

Is there any special term for this kind of clause fronting a clause beginning with 'that?'

Comment: Adverbial clause of reason?Courses in foreign languages are often inadequate training grounds, in and of themselves, for the successful learning of a second language because so much is at stake.

Comment: _So_ is not an adjective, _much_ is not a noun, and the construction at issue is _so X that Y._ One wonders what knowing a name for this will contribute to understanding. BTW, the sentence is unclear as it stands.

Comment: Agreed. Typically `So much is at stake that` is followed by either a statement of what has been done to mitigate the risk, or a statement that something _must_ be done to mitigate the risk; neither of those things follow here.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I've attempted to provide an name for this in a way that will contribute to understanding. I'd welcome your comments.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I don't think it is entirely unreasonable to call "much" a noun in this case: a nounified adjective/determiner.

Comment: _Much_ is specifically a _quantifier_. Quantifiers can also function as pronouns, as here.

Comment: As I think John & Jim are implying, the "logic" of the statement is somewhat faulty. It's not the *extent of the downside if you fail to acquire sufficient fluency* that makes the courses inadequate, it's the *fact that the required level of fluency is very high*. In short, *"so much is at stake"* is simply the wrong phrase to use in this context.

Answer (score 6):

The term is *extraposition*, but for that make sense, I need to correct some of your parsing.

The key construction here is "so […] that […]". For example:

> The snow was **so** *soft* **that** our shoes sank down pretty nearly to the walk. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=KI22AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=so-soft-that)]
>
> The horses are beaten **so** *hard* **that** the tassels from the whips became imprinted on their memories, said Edgar. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=EID4smWDEIgC&pg=PA86&dq=so-hard-that)]
>
> It was just **so** *much* fun **that** it made up for the frustration that might have been. [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=PgNkXvPgVowC&pg=PT65&dq=so-much-fun-that)]

*So* is an adverb modifying an adjective such as *soft*, an adverb such as *hard*, or a determiner such as *much*. The *that*-clause serves as a "complement" to *so*: it completes the meaning. (The word *that* itself, by the way, can frequently be omitted without changing the meaning; hence "I was so happy I sang all day" [[link](http://books.google.com/books?id=QU8AAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=so-happy)], where "I sang all day" is still a *that*-clause, despite the lack of a literal *that*.)

Now, returning to your sentence:

> So much is at stake that courses in foreign languages are often inadequate training grounds, in and of themselves, for the successful learning of a second language.

The subject of this sentence is:

> so much / that courses in foreign languages are often inadequate training grounds, in and of themselves, for the successful learning of a second language

and the predicate is:

> is at stake

("How much is at stake?" "*So much*, that courses in foreign languages are often inadequate training grounds, in and of themselves, for the successful learning of a second language!")

As you can see, the *that*-clause, even though it's part of the subject, has been separated from the rest of the subject, and put after the predicate. This is called *[extraposition](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsExtraposition.htm)*: the *that*-clause is *extraposed* (*extra-* = "outside", *posed* = "put, positioned, located").

Comment: I think you got it. Technically, it's _Extraposition from NP,_ because it's moving the complement of _much [NP]_, so it doesn't have to leave behind a dummy _it_ subject the way regular Extraposition does.

Comment: But the _so_ [...] _that_ [...] construction should spell out the resulting outcome. I.e., I should be able to turn the sentence around and (using your example) say, "_Because_ the snow was so soft, our shoes nearly sank down to the walk." In the OP's statement _there is no result:_ Because there is so much at stake, courses are inadequate for successful learning. I think the intent of the writer is more along the lines of: _Because so much is at stake and because of their inadequacies, foreign language courses should not be used in isolation when learning a second language._

Comment: @Jim: I agree. The sentence is poorly written. (The book that it comes from -- found by Googling -- is riddled with similar errors. For example, "Where does a teacher begin the quest for an understanding of the principles of language learning and teaching? By first considering some of the issues." The author appears to difficulty keeping track of how a given phrase fits, linguistically and conceptually, into its surrounding context.)

Comment: In fact the book is a widely used text for introductory courses teaching methodology in language learning.  Looks like the author needed a better editor.